# How to prove that the intersection of two polyhedrons is still a polyhedron?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've met a problem in M.A.Armstrong's *Basic Topology*.

> If $K$ and $L$ are complexes in $\mathbb{E}^n$, show that $\vert K\vert\cap\vert L\vert$ is a polyhedron.

where $\vert K\vert$ and $\vert L\vert$ are the polyhedron of $K$ and $L$.

I think it's not hard to imagine this statement. But I can't find a formal proof for this.

Can you please help? Thank you.

EDIT：
The definition of a polyhedron in *Basic Topology* is:

> ... the union of the simplexes which make up a particular complex is a subset of a euclidean space, and can therefore be made into a topological space by giving it the subspace topology. A complex $K$, when regarded in this way as a topological space, is called a **polyhedron** and written $\vert K\vert$.

Comment: What if the two polyhedra touch each other's faces?

Comment: What does |X| is the polyhedron of X mean?

Comment: @M.B. : I've edited the post for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon very little knowledge, here is my guess: If a polyhedron is the intersection of half-spaces, then the intersection of two polyhedrons would be the intersection of all the half-spaces in both, and would thus be a polyhedron.

This seems too easy, so I am sure I have stepped into something, but I don't know what.

Comment: Except for "polyhedrons" (I *know* it is said to be correct) your answer is perfectly fine :)

Comment: @marty:Thank you for your idea. Well, the definition of a polyhedron given in the problem may be different from yours. Here it is not necessarily intersection of half-spaces, since it may not be convex.

Comment: A polyhedron is the union of simplices, any two intersecting in a (possibly empty) face of both. A simplex is the intersection of half-spaces, but not every intersection of half-spaces is a simplex (take a plane square). Thus the proof has a gap.